# MATLAB: max filename length for exporting graphs

Tags: matlab, printing, plot, filenames, maxlength

I'm batch processing statistical analyses and need to save down graphs as part of the output. I want to include some parameters settings as part of the graphs' filenames, to associate them easier at a later stage. 
However, if I the FileName is 'too long' the print command throws errors. MATLAB Help is silent on this issue.

```
h = figure;
plot(somedata, moredata);
FileName = strcat(Name(1),'_',Name(2),'_',num2str(a),'_',num2str(b),'_','.jpeg');
print(h,'-djpeg',FileName);
```

Any idea how many chars 'too long' is?

Comment: What kind of length are we talking? Max filename length for Windows is 255 characters.

Comment: @excaza - I think that the limit you mentioned is that of the full path, not just the filename.

Comment: @excaza: 15 chars including filetype works, above 30 doesn't. pedestrian iteration would give the answer, if I find the time I'll post the answer.